# How to aggregate column values to build a pie chart using Google script?

Tags: aggregate

### I have data from a Google sheet like the example below:

1. Title
2. Male
3. Female
4. Male
5. Male

   In Google sheets, there is two check box named "use row 1 as headers" and "aggregate column" that I usually use to create a pie chart. Now, I would like to do the same programming through Google Scripts.

   May someone help me out?

Thanks
Doria

Answer (score 0):

I have outline the sample code which can intelligently aggregate the array item counts for piechart .

I personally dislike and hate the complication as Google seemed to restrict and defined  EmbeddedPieChartBuilder  chart data input as the matrix variables which can only be  derived from Sheet "Range" region bound values  , user therefore have no other choice but force to assign the chart plot value range with a minimum  of two columns matrix. The default standard DataTable offer by Chart can not be used also as plot input.

If the chart is to publish as web , just simply use Charts.newPieChart() syntax

```
function newChart() {

   var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sourcedata');

   var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");

   var rows=range.getNumRows();


   var cols=range.getNumColumns();


   var varr=[]; // To Store  number of items in your range
   var cnt_varr={}; // TO store and  aggregate total item count 
   var chk_item="";
   array_cnt=-1; 
// build up the datatable;  

 // row start is at 2  since row 1 is Title


 for (var vrow=2;vrow<rows+1;vrow++){
    var vitem=range.getCell(vrow, cols).getValue();


   if (vitem!=chk_item){

    cnt=cnt_varr[vitem];
   if (cnt==null){
     // only add new item to array
   varr.push(vitem);

   } 



    chk_item=vitem;
   }


   var cnt=0;
   cnt=cnt_varr[vitem];
   if (cnt==null){
       cnt=0;
   }

   var val_cnt=parseInt(cnt);

   val_cnt=val_cnt+1;
 // intelligently aggregate the array item count 
   cnt_varr[vitem]=val_cnt;



   }


// write the output result to new sheet  


 var new_sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('output');

if (new_sheet==null){
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet().setName("output");
}

new_sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('output');
var row_ToAdd=varr.length;

for (var i=0;i<row_ToAdd;i++){
new_sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(varr[i]);
new_sheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(cnt_varr[varr[i]]);


}
 // PieChartBuilder    


  var chartBuilder = new_sheet.newChart().asPieChart()
  .addRange(new_sheet.getRange(1, 1, row_ToAdd, 2))
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
      .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
      .build();

       //Show the pieChart

    if (new_sheet.getCharts().length>0){

       new_sheet.getCharts().pop();

   } else{ 


   new_sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to run your example, to understand it, but I got the following error: "Cannot find method getRange(number,number). (line 60, file "example4")", pointing to the following line:                                                                                  for(var i = 0;i < row_ToAdd;i++) {
     new_sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(varr[i]); <<<=== HERE!!!
     new_sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(cnt_varr[varr[i]]);

   }

Comment: getRange  doc    https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns

Comment: Have you verify that your spreadsheet successfully created the "output" work sheets yet ?  This got nothing to do with the getrange , it is the variables in varr  and  cnt_varr  object array, you must make sure this is created programmatically correct .

Comment: Expected array result using your eg ---> cnt_varr={Male=3.0,  Female=1.0}
varr=[Male,Female] , use Logger.log(varr) to see the output

Comment: for (var row in varr) {
     for (var col in cnt_varr[row]) {
       Logger.log(varr[row][col]);
     }
   }                                                                                                                      Now I ran into the following error message "No user logs found. Please run your script and try again." after clicking on View, Logs menu.

Comment: on time, the run time error continues the same "Cannot find method getRange(number,number). (line 67, file "example4")". I would like to post here all code, but comments can't be that long. About the spreadsheet, I created it before and use open by id method. "var new_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1eqDiSkdW2_cNjXn_iBIWWpoywY5LmRJ8Ir6FS9UWWMw');"

Comment: Hi TSG! Just coming back to say that I worked it out now and to thank you for all help provided.

Comment: ok , anyway full sample code is shared via the link below, I still think that embedded chart should consider the standard  DataTable input.

Answer (score 0):

I have revised the sample so that existing chart could be dynamically update with new values refresh

```
 if (new_sheet.getCharts().length>0){
       var xcht=new_sheet.getCharts()[0];
       xcht=xcht.modify()
        .addRange(new_sheet.getRange(1, 1, row_ToAdd, 2))
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
         .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
        .build()
      new_sheet.updateChart(xcht);


      // new_sheet.getCharts().pop();


   } else{ 


     new_sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sample Google Sheets with the code shared Hyper Link Click](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOjimN5NNBtyQu3nxdDRx-YrpHXsSu8cbFL0V2x8xfU/edit?usp=sharing)