# How do you set the Chart Aggregate setting from Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am adding charts to a Google Sheet using Google Script

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
.addRange(sheetdata.getRange("E2:E99"))
.setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
.setOption("title", "Leads")
.build();

sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Aggragate
[image: Aggragate]

How do you set the Aggregate from Google Script. I have looked in the doco but cannot see it.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: There is no straight method in Apps Script that offers the `Aggregate` option from Sheets. You can check a workaround in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142327). Could you please share your anonymized spreadsheet so we all can help you better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Many Chart options for EmbeddedChartBuilder.setOption() function not available to Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009364/many-chart-options-for-embeddedchartbuilder-setoption-function-not-available-t)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594839/google-apps-script-how-to-set-use-column-a-as-labels-in-chart-embedded-in-spr

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me, simply add this to your chart

`.setOption('applyAggregateData',0)`